# How to inserting data into multiple SQL tables and create unique ID for each values

Tags: sql-server

As an example my database has 3 tables: `People_Table`, `Address_Table` and `Gender_Table`.

I want to insert

```
"First_Name", "Last_Name"
```

to the `People_Table` and

```
"Address_Line1", "Address_Line2", "City" & "Zip_Code"
```

to the `Address_Table`, and

```
"F" or "M"
```

to the `Gender_Table`.

For each entry I need to create a unique identifier with 8 character. The ID  should look like this `"N0000001", "N0000002", "N0000023"`

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: There is only 3 tables. What is the 4th one?

Answer (score 1):

You're making a mistake by making the database unique key the same as a visual business key.

You should instead use identity columns for your primary key (they autoincrement without any code required). Then you can create a calculated column on your table that for example turns the number 34563 into N0034563

What happens when your ID gets bigger than 9999999?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a sequence table which have two columns number and tablegroupid. And you should create insert trigger. On trigger look sequence table for max number. And make them +1. Concatenate your prefix. And generate your custom identifier.

Comment: Follow this instructions only in a quiet environment. Figure out next PK value using MAX becomes in a big lock.

Comment: Also you should insert them in transaction.

Comment: Even in a transaction, this approach is **NOT** safe in a busy system. Stop doing stuff like this - use the built-in mechanism of `INT IDENTITY` if you need increasing numerical values - that's the only safe and reliable way to go

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

**CREATE TABLES:**

```
CREATE TABLE People_Table (
    id_key VARCHAR(8)
    ,id INT
    ,firstname VARCHAR(50)
    ,lastname VARCHAR(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE Address_Table (
    id_key VARCHAR(8)
    ,Address_Line1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,Address_Line2 VARCHAR(50)
    ,City VARCHAR(50)
    ,Zip_Code VARCHAR(5)
    );

CREATE TABLE Gender_Table (
    id_key VARCHAR(8)
    ,Gender VARCHAR(1)
    );
```

**CREATE PROC:**

Create a procedure to take your insert values as parameters and create separate insert statements for each table. Take `max(id)` from `People_Table` and increase by 1 before inserting it. To create your unique identifier key value, concatenate `N` and replication of `0`'s with your `max(id) + 1`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test_multipleinsert (
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@LastName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,@AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50)
    ,@city VARCHAR(50)
    ,@zipcode VARCHAR(5)
    ,@gender VARCHAR(1)
    )
AS
DECLARE @uniqueidentifier VARCHAR(8)
    ,@maxrowid INT;

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    SET @maxrowid = 0;

    SELECT @maxrowid = max(id) + 1
    FROM People_table;

SET @uniqueidentifier = 'N' + right(replicate(0, 7) + cast(@maxrowid AS VARCHAR(7)), 7);

    INSERT INTO People_Table (
        id_key
        ,id
        ,firstname
        ,lastname
        )
    VALUES (
        @uniqueidentifier
        ,@maxrowid
        ,@firstName
        ,@lastName
        );

  INSERT INTO Address_Table (
        id_key
        ,Address_Line1
        ,Address_Line2
        ,City
        ,Zip_Code
        )
    VALUES (
        @uniqueidentifier
        ,@AddressLine1
        ,@AddressLine2
        ,@city
        ,@ZipCode
        );

    INSERT INTO Gender_Table (
        id_key
        ,Gender
        )
    VALUES (
        @uniqueidentifier
        ,@gender
        );
END
```

**EXECUTE PROC TO INSERT VALUES:**

```
EXEC dbo.test_multipleinsert @FirstName = 'Michael'
    ,@LastName = 'Jordan'
    ,@AddressLine1 = '123 Main Street'
    ,@AddressLine2 = 'Apt#12'
    ,@City = 'CHICAGO'
    ,@ZipCode = '64601'
    ,@Gender = 'M';

EXEC dbo.test_multipleinsert @FirstName = 'Mark'
,@LastName = 'Johnson'
,@AddressLine1 = '456 Main Street'
,@AddressLine2 = 'Apt#89'
,@City = 'Atlanta'
,@ZipCode = '75859'
,@Gender = 'M';

SELECT *
FROM people_table;

SELECT *
FROM address_table;

SELECT *
FROM gender_table;
```

As a side note, your table  is going to hit some major issues due to the your limitations on number of records you can have between 1 and 9999999 only.

Comment: Follow this instructions only in a quiet environment. Figure out next PK value using MAX becomes in a big lock